# how to limit dropdown items in autocomplete textbox c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a textbox with autocomplete mode. When I enter first few characters, the suggestion list items exceeds more than 15.
I want the suggestion items to show maximum of 10 items.

I don't find property to do it.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection ac = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
ac.AddRange(this.Source());

if (textBox1 != null)
{
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ac;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

Comment: return top 10 then from data

Comment: ``textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ac.Take(10)``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad ac.Take() method is not available.

Comment: @CSTRAIZE Include System.Linq; and you will have the Take() extension available on any ICollection.

Comment: @Mangist Still it is not available. I am already using System.Linq; headerfile

Comment: See my answer below @CSTRAIZE

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LINQ on the AutoCompleteStringCollection class. I suggest you handle the filtering yourself in the TextChanged event of the TextBox. I have written some test code below. After entering some text, we will filter and take the top 10 matches from your Source() data set. Then we can set a new AutoCompleteCustomSource for your TextBox. I tested it and this works:

```
private List<string> Source()
{
    var testItems = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++)
    {
        testItems.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    return testItems;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var topTenMatches = this.Source().Where(s => s.Contains(textBox1.Text)).Take(10);
    var autoCompleteSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autoCompleteSource.AddRange(topTenMatches.ToArray());

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteSource;
}
```

Comment: It works. But I cant able to scroll down using "KEY DOWN" key to select a value. When I press "KEY DOWN", first value is taken in textbox and dropdown closes

Comment: Instead of TextChanged event then, use KeyDown, and only refresh the list if the key is not Up/Down.

Comment: KeyDown event is also not working. Keydown event is not triggering when the up key or down key is used in suggestion dropdown.