# TextBox.Text without the suffix of the appended part of Autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to get the Text in a TextBox that has an Autocomplete that appends text, but without the part that is appended? I want to use this text in the Textbox_TextChanged-event. This code doesn't work

```
private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var t = textbox.Text.Substring(0, textbox.SelectionStart);
}
```

It seems the TextChanged-event fires when the autocomplete-text is appended, but the selection of the appended text is applied after that.

E.g. if the user types in `ho` and the autocomplete has an entry `house`, the textbox contains the text `house`, but the `use` is selected and can be overwritten when the user continues typing. I want to get the `ho`-part, because that is the text the user has typed in, without the `use`-part, which doesn't come from the user.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing, could you provide an example of what you are seeing and how that is different from what you expect/want.

Answer (score 1):

Question is some what confusing, I have provide an answer as I understood it.

Text change event fires when you change text in the textbox. You can use suggest instead of appending it

> Assume that textbox name is "Textbox1"

```
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Textbox1.AutoCompleteMode = 
  System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
  var t = Textbox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if possible I want to use AutocompleteMode.Append, to not have a list covering other controls below the textbox.

Comment: Can you try limiting the items in the textbox. I found below reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381891/how-to-limit-dropdown-items-in-autocomplete-textbox-c

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a delay, so the textbox has time to apply the selection. This seems to work so far, but could be an issue if the applying of the selection takes longer than the wait-time.

```
private async void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    var t = textbox.Text.Substring(0, textbox.SelectionStart);
}
```